# How to Include node modules in webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I trying build electron app with "electron-react-boilerplate"

I installed whatsapp-web.js in package.json.. It works fine in development but not in production (after build)

After build, no whatsapp-web.js module included in pakckage. i already tweak webpack configuration but still no result.. the module not included.. and not running in production app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful in solving the issue
http://www.matthiassommer.it/software-architecture/webpack-node-modules/